# Accordion within an Accordion

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to place an accordion within an accordion. but the second accordion isn't working properly. The accordion within the first one isn't functioning at all. Any help would be appreciated :) My question is mostly code so I am typing this out to see if extra space just written helps with anything.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.accordion {
    background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
    color: rgb(15, 15, 15);
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  
  .active, .accordion:hover {
    background-color: rgb(185, 185, 185);
  }
  
  .accordion:after {
    content: '\002B';
    color: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }
  
  .active:after {
    content: "\2212";
  }
  
  .panel {
    font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Accordion</h2>
<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div class="panel">
  <button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>
      content
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your accordion within the parent accordion is working as expected. Its just that we cannot see that it is working, reason being, when you expand the child accordion, you should also consider reassigning `panel.style.maxHeight` to the parent accordion aslo.

Right now, you set `panel.style.maxHeight` to the panel of the accordion being clicked but the parent accordion doesn't know that its child has expanded. So when the child accordion expand you will have to re assign `panel.style.maxHeight` to the parent accordion panel.

Try refactoring the code and let me know your progress.